# Hyper-elliptic curves and mapping class groups

Tags: elliptic-curves, mapping-class-group

> What is the relation between hyper-elliptic mapping class groups and
>   hyper-elliptic curves?

I have seen the tag hyper-elliptic curves under a few articles about hyper-elliptic mapping class group and no mention of any curve in the body of the article. The whole things screams that there is a reason these subgroup of a mapping class group was named hyper-elliptic.